# storage duration of functions, structs, classes, enums, and unions

Tags: c++

If global variables and objects have static storage duration and external linkage?

do functions have static storage duration and external linkage as well?

what about structs and classes and enumerators(has external linkage i know)/unions?

I figured they have no storage duration and have no linkage,but then i thought that (global)functions have external linkage by default,but in a class they have class scope do they have internal linkage or?

Answer (score 2):

Storage duration and linkage are unrelated concepts.

Functions do not have "storage duration", since functions do not reside in storage. Only objects have storage duration. Types do not reside in storage either, which is why types do not have storage duration.

It is not correct to say that classes have no linkage in general. Named classes declared in namespace scope have external linkage. Member functions of classes with external linkage also have external linkage. Classes declared locally and nameless classes have no linkage.

Comment: well i dont mean specifically...I mean when you declare them at file scope...they have no linkage right?

Comment: Who's "them"? In any case, almost every named entity (function, object, type) in C++ that is declared at file scope has *external* linkage, unless it is declared as `static` (where applicable).

Comment: i am referring to structs classes  and unions at file scope..when you extern you have to redefine? correct and when you redefine it can be different members(structs for example)...so how can they have external linkage? i know the instantion has external linkage..?

Comment: All names classes, structs, enums and unions declared at file scope have external linkage. I don't understand what you mean by "when you extern" and "you have to redefine". You are not allowed to have a file scope class with the same name, but different members in different files. You are absolutely *required*, no exceptions, to define all classes with the same name absolutely identically in all files. If you violate this requirement, your program is broken.

Comment: Also, another quick question when you call a global variable inside a functions the variable is re-created correct?...why can you create a variable once in the global namespace but be able to call it multiple times in a function?

Comment: well if a class or struct or enum or union has external linkage then why cant i make a forward declaration of them in a another file,but I can with functions?

Comment: Er.. Nothing is "recreated". A global variable is called global for a reason. It exists as a single object form the very start of the program, and it exists forever (i.e. until the program ends). All functions in all translation units access the very same global variable. I don't understand your "why can you..." question since I don't see where it is comping from.

Comment: @Voide Re: What made you think that you should be able to "make a forward declaration of them in a another file" for classes? The concept of "external linkage" never promised you anything like that. The requirements of "external linkage" are different for different kinds of entities. They are different for classes, they are different for functions.

Comment: ohh okay....that just got me confused so only block variables have no linkage correct?

Comment: Basically, what "external linkage" means is that the same name shall/will refer to the same entity in all translation units. Sometimes it is you who's burdened with the task of ensuring it, e.g. required to declare the class identically in all translation unit.

Comment: Also, when you call a function inside another function...does that mean the (function identifier variable) is allocated when the code block begins and deallocated when it ends? does the function become like a variable in that sense? does the function get recreated when its called?

Comment: so, when you use the extern keyword for a struct lets say...you have to redefine the struct? that is okay?

Comment: @Voide Re: It is important to understand that the linkage is actually a property of a *name*, not of the entity hiding behind that name. Yes, local names have no linkage (unless explcitly declared with linkage specifiers). Names of non-static data members of a class also have no linkage.

Comment: @Voide Re: I don't understand what you mean by "extern keyword for a struct". `extern` keyword can be applied to the name of an *object* of class type. It cannot be applied to the class itself.

Comment: There's no such thing as "function identifier variable". Functions exists from the very beginning of the program. When you call a function (no matter from where), you just call a function. When function starts, it will allocate its local variables. Local variables are allocated. Function itself does not need to be "allocated". It already exists.

Comment: so I have to have a instance of the actual class in that file for I to be able to access the members through a extern'd object?

Comment: also, why can you only call inside a function with the auto storage class...? why cant i call in the global namespace and re-assign it a value perhaps?

Comment: " When function starts, it will allocate its local variables. " so the variables are recreated? and allocated and deallocated just means created and destroyed right?

Comment: also, in the main function return 0 means exit_success and any other value means exit_failure or error? which one? and I can create the errors using cerr right?

Answer (score 0):

Functions don't officially have a storage duration, but in essence they're static (i.e., every function exists for the entire duration of the program). They have internal linkage if you define them `static` or inside of an anonymous namespace, otherwise external linkage.

Storage class applies to an object, not a type definition like a class, struct or union. It's fairly common to have two objects of the same class, one with static storage duration, and another with auto storage duration.

Likewise, you could create one object with internal linkage and another with external linkage:

```
T x;
static T y;
```

The same goes for linkage of classes:

```
class X { }; // external linkage

namespace { 
   class Y {}; // internal linkage
};
```